# Как вернуть ранее установленные программы на Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ос, обновление

Я очень долго не обновлял свою ОС. Однако Центр Обновлений выдавал ошибку о том, что не может меня обновить и сказал перейти по ссылке, которая являлась оффициальным сайтом Microsoft и там скачать обновление. После того, как мой компьютер обновился ВСЕ программы удалились, остались лишь мои личные файлы. Я знаю, что Windows в таких случаях создаёт папку Windows.old и она у меня имеется. Там также есть папки Program Files и Program Files(x86). Так как мне восстановить эти программы корректно? Подскажите, пожалуйста. Буду очень благодарен

Comment: *Центр Обновлений выдавал ошибку о том, что не может меня обновить и сказал перейти по ссылке, которая являлась официальным сайтом Microsoft и там скачать обновление.* Укажите точно ссылку и название применённого обновления.

Comment: Вот ссылка: https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/software-download/windows10
Далее я нажал обновить. Обновление, вроде бы, на 1903 версию

Comment: Хотя, это довольно странно. Я обновлялся до 1903, а команда winver, говорит, что моя версия 2004

Comment: А какая версия ОС стояла до этого? и насколько она была лицензионно чистая? По опыту - использовал Upgrade wizard на более чем 20 компьютерах - ни разу не было ничего описанного, за исключением удаления ПО, несовместимого с Windows 10.

Comment: До этого у меня стояла та же Windows 10, на неё также была лицензия. Ничего пиратского на моём компьютере не было

Comment: *Я обновлялся до 1903, а команда winver, говорит, что моя версия 2004* Upgrade wizard сейчас обновляет до ver. 1909 build 18363.836. Правда, я использую только 1803 версию. По сабжу - не вижу иного способа восстановить программы кроме отката обновления.

Comment: Спасибо. Но неужели нету способа просто корректно перенести файлы из Windows.old\Program Files и Windows.old\Program Files (x86) в C:\Program Files (x86) и C:\Program Files?

Comment: Большинство программ для корректной работы требуют соответствующих изменений на диске и в реестре. Были ли они перенесены при обновлении? а вот не факт. Можно попробовать тупо скопировать соответствующие каталоги из старых Program Files / ProgramData / AppData и запуститься...